# How to test for two segments intersecting, excluding their endpoints?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given two segments, for example

> S1=(2,1)-(2,3)
>   S2=(7,8)-(2,3)

the intersection test would be false.

However, if I use the cross-products test the result is true. I understand the two segments have a point in common but is there a way to exclude those endpoints from the test?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly they intersect at (2,3) . Run a dry run by co-ordinate geometry. :)

Comment: Yes clearly they do. My problem is with the using of the cross-products technique to test for the intersection reporting that they intersects however I do not want the endpoints participating in the intersection.

Comment: Only the end pont (2,3) is intersecting and no other points do

Comment: I know, I don't want (2,3) as the intersection. I want the test to report that there is no intersection in this case.